# SQL Query in Apache Derby

Tags: sql, database, derby

I'm working on a side project with a Apache Derby database and I'm having trouble with a query.  I have the following two tables:

```
    create table Employee(
    ID VARCHAR(7) not null, 
    lname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     avgPieces int, 
    PRIMARY KEY(ID));

   create table Record(
   emp_id VARCHAR(7) references Employee(ID), 
   day DATE NOT NULL,
   pieces int NOT NULL, 
   numMisloads int);
```

I'm trying to get a query to return sum(pieces)/sum(numMisloads) for a given employee.  I have the following query but I get an error saying that since there is an aggregate all the returns need to have a valid aggregate.

```
    SELECT lname, fname, (SUM(Record.pieces)/SUM(Record.numMisloads)) 
FROM Employee, Record Where Employee.id = Record.emp_id GROUP BY Employee.id;
```

Pretty stuck, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to use `(SUM(Record.pieces)/SUM(Record.numMisloads)) AS varname`

Answer (score 1):

What I do in those situations is using FIRST() on lname, because lname is always the same. 
It feels like a dirty work-around so I hope somebody comes up with a better solution.

```
SELECT FIRST(lname), FIRST(fname), (SUM(Record.pieces)/SUM(Record.numMisloads)) 
FROM Employee, Record Where Employee.id = Record.emp_id GROUP BY Employee.id;
```

Comment: If you take lname and fname out of the query, does it return the desired results? If yes, then you are using it correct.

Comment: it does indeed give the desired results if i take out the lname and fname hmmm....

Comment: I added the query to the answer.

Comment: SELECT lname, fname, (SUM(Record.pieces)/SUM(Record.numMisloads)) FROM Employee, Record Where Employee.id = Record.emp_id GROUP BY Employee.lname, Employee.fname, Employee.id;

Comment: just had to add 2 more fields in the group by